# jq command returning null

Tags: json, sh, jq

I have the below json content in my sample file but while using the `jq` command the result is always null:

```
{
    "listingRequest": {
        "id": "016a1050-82dc-1262-cc9b-4baf3e0b7123",
        "uri": "http://localhost:9090/nifi-api/flowfile-queues/016a104a-82dc-1262-7d78-d84a704abfbf/listing-requests/016a1050-82dc-1262-cc9b-4baf3e0b7123",
        "submissionTime": "04/28/2019 19:40:58.593 UTC",
        "lastUpdated": "19:40:58 UTC",
        "percentCompleted": 0,
        "finished": false,
        "maxResults": 100,
        "state": "Waiting for other queue requests to complete",
        "queueSize": {
            "byteCount": 480,
            "objectCount": 20
        },
        "sourceRunning": false,
        "destinationRunning": false
    }
}
```

I want to retrieve the value of the byte count i.e. byteCount. The result should be 480.

But below is the output that I get:

```
cat queue.json | jq -r '.byteCount'
null
```

I just found out that jq tool cannot be installed in our servers due to restrictions.

How do I do it via sed/grep? I tried  `grep -Po '"byteCount":.*?[^\\]",'` but did not get any output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the full path:

```
$ jq '.listingRequest.queueSize.byteCount' file.json
480
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to specifying the full path is to use `..`, e.g.

```
$ jq '.. | .byteCount? // empty' queue.json 
480
```